# Cannot create indexed view

Tags: sql-server, view

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
   order_no INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   prod_id INT NOT NULL,
   quantity INT
);

CREATE VIEW product_stats WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
SELECT a.prod_id, a.product_name, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.orders WHERE prod_id = a.prod_id) AS total FROM dbo.products a;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Order_Details_X] 
       ON product_stats (prod_id, total)
```

It complains:
Column 'total' in view 'product_stats' cannot be used in an index or statistics or as a partition key because it does user or system data access.

DB is ms sql.

Comment: You may want to consider marking some of the 17 answers you've received as "accepted;" it'll make visitors more likely to put an effort into answering your questions.

Answer (score 6):

An indexed view cannot contain `COUNT(*)` or a subquery. See the "View Restrictions" section of [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120).

Comment: +1 unfortunately a rather looong list of restrictions - but indexed views are a big boost to performance, if you can stay within those restrictions!

Comment: But it can contain COUNT_BIG(*)